# S3 input plugin is failing when running logstash on kubernetes

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, logstash

I am running logstash on kubernetes and using s3 input plugin to read logs from S3 and send it to elasticsearch. Pod is being crashloopback with the below error. Can someone help me with this issue?

error:

```
[2020-05-06T05:20:53,995][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>42, "name"=>"[main]<s3", "current_call"=>"uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/protocol.rb:181:in `wait_readable'"}]
{"thread_id"=>41, "name"=>"[main]>worker7", "current_call"=>"[...]/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:262:in `block in start_workers'"}]}}
[2020-05-06T05:20:48,651][ERROR][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt]
```

Comment: It is a new deployment or stopped to work suddenly? Could you confirm if your pod is able to reach and retrieve data from s3?

Comment: @KoopaKiller after 5 or 6 restarts its able to reach and retrieve data from S3. But is there any reason why its being restarted 5 or 6 times when deployed?